# Access extra parameters in Ratchet web socket requests

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I've set up [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) for websockets in PHP . It is connecting fine from my javascript client using (ws://localhost:8080) and successfully send/receive messages. But I want to pass some params like (ws://localhost:8080?param1=value). I'm not able to figure out **how can I access param1 in my PHP script**.

If possible in MessageComponentInterface::onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) method.

Or better: Can I associate those params with ConnectionInterface $conn. So that I've them for further communication.

I've followed  http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965445/how-to-access-guzzle-querystring-parameters-in-ratchet-websockets

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of [a very recent update](https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet/pull/143), you can now access this like so:

```
function onOpen( ConnectionInterface $conn ) {
   $querystring = $conn->WebSocket->request->getQuery();
}
```

I actually just ran into this issue myself. Tested this and it's working perfectly.

Comment: hi, i was just trying this url  ws://localhost:8080?userid=1
and i tried to parse querystring using  $querystring = $conn->WebSocket->request->getQuery();
print_r($conn->WebSocket->request->getQuery());

But it print
Guzzle\Http\QueryString Object
(
    [fieldSeparator:protected] => &
    [valueSeparator:protected] => =
    [urlEncode:protected] => RFC 3986
    [aggregator:protected] => 
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: Its working fine.When i print the $querystring its showing as below                Guzzle\Http\QueryString Object
(
    [fieldSeparator:protected] => &
    [valueSeparator:protected] => =
    [urlEncode:protected] => RFC 3986
    [aggregator:protected] =>
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 10
            [receiver_id] => 20
        )

)   now how to get the user_id and receiver_id

Comment: `$query = $conn->WebSocket->request->getQuery()->toArray();`

Comment: Because it implements the `ToArrayInterface`

Comment: As of writing this comment, this worked for me: `$conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getPath()`

Comment: As for today, this works for me:
`$querystring = $conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery();`
`parse_str($querystring,$queryarray);`
// your data is in $queryarray

Comment: How do you get array index

Answer (score 7):

In symfony 4 with php > 7.1

```
$conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery()
```

This return all parameters into the query, only need parse string to extract the paremeter that needs.

Comment: Answers that work so far.

Answer (score 4):

```
$conn->WebSocket->request
```

replaced with

```
$conn->httpRequest
```

which is a PSR-7 object

https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md