# How to access Guzzle QueryString parameters in Ratchet WebSockets?

Tags: php, guzzle, ratchet

Hi I am using radchet websocket. I am getting trouble to get my data from an object variable.

Please check my code:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080?user_id=10&receiver_id=20');
$querystring = $conn->WebSocket->request->getQuery();
print_r($querystring);
```

Output:

```
Guzzle\Http\QueryString Object
(
    [fieldSeparator:protected] => &
    [valueSeparator:protected] => =
    [urlEncode:protected] => RFC 3986
    [aggregator:protected] =>
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 10
            [receiver_id] => 20
        )
)
```

Above code i want `user_id` and `receiver_id` but i am unable to get.

My code:

```
echo $querystring->data:protected['user_id'];
echo $querystring->data:protected['receiver_id'];
```

I have echoed but getting error message. Please help me.

***EDIT:***

If I convert object to array it is not showing proper format. see below.

```
$array =  (array)  $querystring;
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [ * fieldSeparator] => &
    [ * valueSeparator] => =
    [ * urlEncode] => RFC 3986
    [ * aggregator] =>
    [ * data] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 10
            [receiver_id] => 20
        )

)
```

Comment: `protected` is the visibility of your property. And since it is protected you need a public method to call it from outside of the class!

Comment: I cant imagine why you want get the same values you send to the request. Maybe you can get from the request directly?

Comment: How to get directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Guzzle\Http\QueryString](http://api.guzzlephp.org/class-Guzzle.Http.QueryString.html) extends [Guzzle\Common\Collection](http://api.guzzlephp.org/class-Guzzle.Common.Collection.html) so you should be able to use Collection's methods:

```
$user_id = $querystring->get('user_id');
$receiver_id = $querystring->get('receiver_id');
```

or

```
$parameters = $querystring->toArray();
$user_id = $parameters['user_id'];
$receiver_id = $parameters['receiver_id'];
```

Comment: Thank you Furgas and  chatfun .i was having same problem.