# RatchetPHP no WebSocket property for new connections

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, ratchet

I'm trying to access the query parameters for incoming connections in a Websocket server's `onOpen` function using Ratchet. Both the [official documentation](http://socketo.me/docs/websocket) and other [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761900/access-extra-parameters-in-ratchet-web-socket-requests) posts say that you can do this by accessing the `WebSocket` property of the `ConnectionInterface` object passed to the function:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $query = $conn->WebSocket->request->getQuery();
}
```

However, there's no `WebSocket` property for incoming connection objects. When I start this server and connect with a client, a notice is given, which results in a fatal error for calling a function on a `null` object:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Ratchet\Server\IoConnection::$WebSocket

I'm using PHP 7.0 and I'm requiring the latest stable release in my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.3.6"
}
```

I'm connecting the client in a Chrome JS console with code copied directly from the [Hello World](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) documentation as well:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080?foo=bar');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};
```

If it's helpful, the only public properties I see for `$conn` are:

```
bufferSize
stream
readable
writable
closing
loop
buffer
listenerse
decor
```

Comment: hmm... im not sure where is that in the documentation, can you provide the link? Usually you have to declare and 'use' the particular namespace, then call that class. Do you still remember which class it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and I found that :

```
 $querystring = $conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery();
 parse_str($querystring,$queryarray);
```

allows you to access the query parameters.